# Problems with IBM Integration Bus 10.0.0.4 on VMWare

Tags: multithreading, vmware, ibm-integration-bus

we are running IBM Integration Bus 10.0.0.4 on Red Had Linux on a VMWare cluster
and are facing thread hangings since the stuff has been moved to new hardware
and VMWare version.
Is there anybody out there who has similar problems?

Kind regards

Klaus

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem running integration nodes on Windows 10. You can try to install a lower version.